# Regex java operators

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex `.+\s*(?=!|<|>|=|LIKE)` and it doesnt work.

I want to match everything on the left side to the operators <,>,<=,>=,=,!=,LIKE.

Obviously my regex doesn't do the work so I am wondering if you could help me.

Check out what is wrong on this link: https://regex101.com/r/skRdTr/1
(it matches everything on the left side, including >,<,! if operator is <=,>=,!=)

Comment: regex has LIKE and you expect LESS in your second sentence. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `(\w+\s+)(=|LIKE|<|>|>=|<=|!=){1}`

Comment: This should do it `(.+?)(?=[!<>=]+|LIKE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: `.+?\s*(?=!|<|>|=|LIKE)`.

Comment: `.+?` is the same as `.*` isn't it?

Comment: `+?` is "lazy match one or more" and `.*` is "greedy match zero or more".  The OP's problem was with the two digit operators:  The greedy left-side would capture the first digit, since the lookahead was happy to match the other.  Also, @i_rezic the `\s*` portion of your regex isn't doing anything.